# How can I keep my scroll bar size(length) as stable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scenario here, there is a `div` parent element. it has the `css` value as `overflow:auto`. when the user keep add multiple element, the `overflow` works, but the size of the scroll bar going small. (that's common!)

What i looking is, i don't want to make my `scroll` bars height became small or big. i would like to keep my `scrollbar` height became static, whatever the length of elements appended.

So I trying to `hide` and `show` the nested elements under the parent. instead of resizing the scroll bar i re-sizing the content.

I don't have much idea about this. but nearly i tried to get the one what i look.

but not get the result.

here is my code :

```
var $newdiv = $('.div');
    $col = $('<div />');

var container = $('#content');
var n = 0;
var child = $('.show');
var parent =  container;

var add = function () {
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
         $newdiv.clone().removeClass('div').addClass('show')
         .find('span').append(n = n < 9 ? '0'+(++n) : ++n).end().clone().appendTo($col);
    }

}

$col.appendTo(container);
$('button').click(function () { add()});
$(container).slimScroll({});

container.scroll(function(){
   totalCH = 20*n;
    parentH = parent.outerHeight();
    required = Math.abs(parentH - totalCH);
    scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
    requireToHide = scrolled/20;
    hidableNo = Math.round(requireToHide);

    if(scrolled > lastScrollTop) {
        //while scroll down
        //$(".div:lt("+hidableNo+ ")" ).addClass('hideIt');
        //$(".div:gt("+(n-1)+ ")" ).addClass( "showIt");
    } else {
        //while scroll up
        //$(".div:lt("+(n-1)+ ")" ).addClass("showIt");
        //$(".div:gt("+hidableNo+ ")" ).addClass("hideIt");
    }

    lastScrollTop = scrolled;


});


var lastScrollTop = 0;
```

[Try Online](http://jsfiddle.net/L6q58tf9/14/)

Any one suggest me the correct approach.

Thanks in advance!

**Please avoid plug-in and consider the support ie9**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm going to refer to "scroller" as the draggable element in the scrollbar.*

The scroller changing size is a standard UI representation that lets the user understand the amount of content in the scroll area; the goal of which is also to keep the rate of scrolling of the content to a standard flow rate.

For example, if you have a large amount of content in the scrollable area, dragging on a smaller scroller means that the content will flow at (about) the same speed as having less scrollable content (and a larger scroller).

Having a constant size scroller, will mean that a large amount of content would need to scroll much faster than a smaller amount of content.

To achieve what you want, I believe you're going to need an addon that takes the scroll speed/acceleration into account.

I use: jquery.mCustomscroll bar for custom scrolling behaviors.
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

It even has a setting to do exactly what you want:

```
autoDraggerLength: boolean
```

- Enable or disable auto-adjusting scrollbar dragger length in relation
  to scrolling amount (same behavior with browser’s native scrollbar). 
  Set autoDraggerLength: false when you want your scrollbar to (always)
  have a fixed size.

Comment: I have much confident to correcting a couple of lines to the script it to work. already i have much of plugins added. I am not have any option to use the plug-in. thanks for your help.

Comment: If not using the plugin is possible, then at least view the code of the plugin to determine how to handle the issue of scrollspeed.  Another issue to consider is that many users now use either mouse scrolling or touch/drag for viewing scrolling content, so the user ultimately controls the content flow rate.  This means if you have a static sized scroller, and a lot of content, then as the user manually controls the content flow, it may look like your scroller isn't moving at all, which could be confusing to users.

Comment: Thanks, this is all about clients requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can solved with css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: rgb(41,41,41);
    border-radius: 10px;}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    border-radius:10px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
}
```